# Reactive Slick future response not rendered Play template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-3.0

I am working on Slick 3 + Play Framework and Scala. I don't know why my Play template not rendering data I was getting from Slick DB call first time. When I was refreshing same page again it shows the data but unable to rendered 1st time.

Here is my code,

Slick DB call:

```
def findByAccessToken(Id: String): Future[Option[Organization]] = 
db.run(orgs.filter(_.Id=== Id).result.headOption)
```

Controller Action Call:

```
def getOrgInfo = Action.async { request =>

val maybeOrg = for {
  org <- orgDAO.findByAccessToken(request.session.get("oauthAccessToken").get)
} yield org

maybeOrg.map {
  case org =>
    org match {
      case Some(c) => Ok(views.html.account(c))
      case None => NotFound
    }
}
```

And Final Play Template code:

```
@(Org: Organization)
@container("Org Info") {

<h1>Org Information</h1>

<ul>

    <li>
        User Id: @Org
    </li>
</ul>

}
```

Looks like when 1st time my page loading at that time db call have not yet delivered result but because when I was refreshing it shows data.

How to handle this scenario and rendered data for first time as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this doesn't have anything to do with the template. You could add some debug statements to verify that. Maybe the token does not exist at the moment the first request is fired?

Comment: I think It is not the problem. when I printed my "Id: String" value inside findByAccessToken method I was getting the value of it. Not sure why it is working strange?

Comment: Hi @nemoo, you are partially correct. The exact problem I was found, when I am calling above slick "findByAccessToken" method I was coming from Action.Async action controller and redirecting to this page. So may be 1st time when page loading system could not getting Id and returning the blank value. So in order to fix I have fixed my previous method and forwarding to this page only when I have successfully end up with future response.